# How to reduce blob using aspect ratio?

Tags: matlab, blob, reduce, aspect-ratio

I have a binary image with 4 blobs. 3 of them has an aspect ratio of more than 1. and 1 has aspect ratio of 1. Now I want to reduce that blobs which aspect ratio more than 1 in binary image. How could i do this. Can some one please provide a code??

Here is a link of the binary image. I want to reduce that 3 blobs which has an aspect ratio more than 1. And only want to keep that triangle shape.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mngjlcsin46fgim/demo.png?dl=0

Comment: Please post your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `regionprops` for that , for example:

```
 s=regionprops(bw,'BoundingBox','PixelIdxList');
```

where `bw` is your binary image.

The output of `s.BoundingBox` is a [x,y,width,height] vector
you can loop over s

```
for i=1:numel(s)
    ar(i) = s(i).BoundingBox(3)/s(i).BoundingBox(4)          
end
```

and see if the width/height ratio `ar` (or whatever you define aspect ratio) is approx above 1  or not (because of noise I'd take a value of ar>1.2) . Then for that `i` use you can use the pixel list `s(i).PixelIdxList`

```
 bw(s(ar>1.2).PixelIdxList)=0;
```

to zero these intensities...

Comment: But is it possible to use that **pixelList** in vision.BlobAnalysis. To set pixel values to zero. I have applied another approach that is related to vision.blobAnalysis. I extracted all ROI and calculated their aspect ratio than applied condition _if AspectRatio = 1_ than insert a shape(rectangle) . But other blob remains in the output image. Now i want to set zero to pixelList of those blobs that are not satisfying above condition. And i am now stuck here.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-computer-vision/mw/vision_product-OCRExample-recognize-text-using-optical-character-recognition-ocr?s_tid=srchtitle                                                                             in this documentation i have used following section-         **ROI-based Processing To Improve Results**